# Is it possible to send push notifications to Android without building any application using phone number?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send push notifications to Android without building any application, if I have a phone  number?

Comment: In other words, How may ways are there to retrieve the device ID with out installing app  in android device?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Sending a push notification with GCM requires a registration ID, and in order to obtain a registration ID you must have an application that would register to GCM and send the registration ID to your server.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

If you want to send push notifications, you should have an application registered on GCM. 
GCM gives you an id. You can send notifs with this id over GCM.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**NO, This is not possible at all**

To make push notification working, you must need to obtain GCM Registration id, and that id you will get after Register your application to Google Play Server.

Answer (score 0):

Send an SMS, SMS also works like push notifications.

Comment: Yes, but after sending SMS to the user, when he replies me , can I read device ID from his android phone? Shortly, I need to retrieve DEVICE ID using phone number.